# Is there any chance to get the differnce between users timezone and GMT+0?

Tags: apex, datetime, timezone

I know, how to get my timezone:
`TimeZone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();`

And I know, how to get current time of my timezone:

```
 Datetime now = Datetime.now();
    Integer offset = UserInfo.getTimezone().getOffset(now);
    Datetime local = now.addSeconds(offset/1000);
```

But can we get the time differnce between users timezone and GMT+0? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TimeZone](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_timezone.htm) class can answer these questions. First, get the user's time zone:

```
User u = [SELECT TimeZoneSidKey FROM USER ...];
```

Then, get the TimeZone from the user's record:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(u.TimeZoneSidKey);
```

Then you can get the offset:

```
Integer offSet = tz.getOffSet(DateTime.now());
```

(Specify any specific point in time you'd like to get the offset at that time; this automatically calculates DST if applicable).

Comment: And this is a difference between user with, for ex, GMT+1 and GMT, right?

Comment: @DanDan Yes, that's correct.